# NSFetchRequest many-to-one newest only

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, many-to-one

I am trying to work out the most efficient way of retrieving a single newest result in a many-to-one relationship.

Example:

Entity A - Team (name)
Entity B - Employee (name, created)

Team <-->> Employee

I would like to create a fetch request on Employee which returns the most recently created employee for each team.

Obviously I could iterate over Team and then run a second request to find the newest Employee for that team, but that could get very onerous if there are hundreds of teams and the potential for thousands of employees.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

The proper `sortDescriptor` together with the `fetchBatchSize` set to `1` should do the trick.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 1;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

EDIT: At this point I finally understood the question: how to get the newest employee in each team.
I do not think you can do this with just one `fetchRequest`. But if you think about it, it's quite logical.

```
NSFetchRequest *allTeamsFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Team"];
allTeamsFetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = YES;
NSArray *teams = [context executeFetchRequest:allTeamsFetchRequest error:&error];

NSMutableArray *newPlayers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSManagedObject *team in teams) {
    NSFetchRequest *newPlayerFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
    newPlayerFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];
    newPlayerFetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 1;
    NSArray *players = [context executeFetchRequest:newPlayerFetchRequest error:&error];
    [newPlayers addObjectsFromArray:players];
}
```

So first you add all `Team` objects, note that for this task we can get away with `fault`s, no need to fetch relationships. And then for each `Team` we get the newest player. This is not "one line" solution but it does its job.

Comment: I think this wont work.. you are sort and fetching the recent employee from the employee entity.. where you are using the predicate instance in the code.. ?

Comment: My bad, forgot to assign the predicate, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That would work for a specific team, but I want to return the newest employee for every team, not just a specific one.

Comment: Oh, I did not understand that part. Then you just skip the predicate. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That won't work either because now you just get a single newest employee. I need to get the newest employee in each team.